# Read values from a datatable of a dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I want to search a column of a datatable after values from a textbox. I want to search after ISBN-Numbers

This is my Table "Book":

```
DataColumn bookName = new DataColumn("BookName", typeof(string));
DataColumn bookId = new DataColumn("BookId", typeof(int));
DataColumn isbn = new DataColumn("ISBN", typeof(string)); //should be an EAN-13
 Barcodeenter code here

DataColumn book_authorId = new DataColumn("Book_AuthorId", typeof(int));
DataColumn bookprice = new DataColumn("Price", typeof(decimal));
DataColumn authorName = new DataColumn("AuthorName", typeof(string));
DataColumn authorId = new DataColumn("AuthorId", typeof(int));
DataColumn geschlecht = new DataColumn("Geschlecht", typeof(string));
```

Now, how can I only search the isbn, without I get values from the whole table?
In a Listbox I want to have the Output. There I want to have all Values from the book where the ISBN Number contains the text from the textbox.

My Code I have now to search after the isbn is the following:

```
  string isbn = _tbIsbnSuche.Text;
            string result = String.Empty;
            string file = _tempPath + @"\book_authorData.xml";
            XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(file);
            if (isbn != String.Empty)
            {
                _lbInformation.Text = String.Empty;
                _lBdatenOutput.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                _lBdatenOutput.Items.Clear();
                _lBdatenOutput.Items.Insert(0, "Please Wait!");
                _lBdatenOutput.Items.Insert(1, "Gefundene ISBN-Nummern:");
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    if (r.Value.Trim().IndexOf(isbn) != -1 && r.Value.Trim().Contains("-") && r.Value.Length >= 13)
                    {
                        _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add(r.Value.Trim());
                    }
                }
                tim.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _lbInformation.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                _lbInformation.Text = _suchfehler;
            }
            //Wenn keine Datensätze gefunden wurden
            if (_lBdatenOutput.Items.Count == 2)
            {
                tim.Enabled = true;
                _lBdatenOutput.BackColor = Color.OldLace;
                _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add(String.Concat("Es wurden keine Bücher welche in der ISBN-Nummer die Zeichenfolge ", "\"", isbn, "\"", " enthalten gefunden"));

            }
```

But this searches all of the Dataset and when i have a value in an other field withch is the same as the search string, it appears in the search results too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys I've found a solution. This solutionj may be more complex then needet, but I couldn't found another solution. After some hours I've got following code:

```
string _seperator1 = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n"; 
string isbn = _tbIsbnSuche.Text;
DataView custView = new DataView(_dset.Tables["Book"], "", "ISBN", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
{
    _lBdatenOutput.Items.Clear(); //Delete existing Objects from the Output
    foreach (DataRowView myDRV in custView)
    {
        DataRow dr = myDRV.Row;
        if((dr["ISBN"].ToString().IndexOf(isbn) >= 0))
        {
            foreach (DataColumn cl in custView.Table.Columns)
            {
                _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add("Spalten-Name:  " + " \t " + cl.ColumnName + " \t" + dr[cl]);
            }
            _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add(_seperator1); //Insert a seperator
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I can help someone with this

Answer (score 0):

You can access a `DataRow`'s column via the name, e.g. `row["ISBN"]`